# plot spheres in gnuplot from file

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a file with 4 columns (radius,x,y,z) that contains on each line the coordinates of a sphere and its radius. Could you please help me to plot these spheres in gnuplot? ( If it is not possible in gnuplot, could you recommend another plotting tool?)

Answer (score 6):

There is a `with circles` style option in 2D. In 3D you can pass the radius from the file to the `pointsize` option. Consider the following data:

```
# radius, x, y, z
1 0 0 0
2 1 2 2
3 3 4 5
1 2 5 7
1 1 3 4
2 2 0 1
```

Then you can plot it like this (`ps` is short for `pointsize` and `pt` is short for `pointtype` ; `pt 7` draws circles):

```
splot "data" u 2:3:4:1 ps variable pt 7
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use `u 2:3:4:1`?

Comment: @Christoph Aha! I did not know about `ps variable`! As a matter of fact, this was a completely lucky coincidence: I was using `var` as a variable name, and it just happened to work because it's short for `variable`. So my answer was conceptually wrong. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make nicer plots you have to plot parametric spheres. It is however not possible to have a parametric plot read parameters from a datafile directly.

consider the same following data:

```
# radius, x, y, z
1 0 0 0
2 1 2 2
3 3 4 5
1 2 5 7
1 1 3 4
2 2 0 1
```

The solution to this (in gp 5.1 or higher) is to first read the sphere coordinates from "data" into gnuplot arrays, then loop over the arrays for parametric plots:

```
# find the number of spheres
stats "data" using (0):(0) nooutput
spheres=STATS_records

# define arrays and fill with sphere coordinates
array sphereR[spheres]
array sphereX[spheres]
array sphereY[spheres]
array sphereZ[spheres]
stats "data" using ( sphereR[int($0)+1]=$1,sphereX[int($0)+1]=$2,sphereY[int($0)+1]=$3,sphereZ[int($0)+1]=$4,0):(0) nooutput

# plot spheres
set parametric
set isosamples 10,10
set view equal xyz
set urange[0:2*pi]
set vrange[-pi/2:pi/2]
splot for [i=1:spheres] sphereX[i]+sphereR[i]*cos(v)*sin(u),sphereY[i]+sphereR[i]*cos(v)*cos(u),sphereZ[i]+sphereR[i]*sin(v) with lines title sprintf("sphere %i",i)
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts9vG.png)